# Using Scanner hasNext() and hasNextLine() to retrieve 2 elements per line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

In Java, if you were given a text file with two elements per line, how can we grab those elements separately?

For example say we have a `5 line text file` with the following:

```
a morgan
b stewart
c david 
d alfonso
e brittany
```

and let's say we want to store the single char in a variable and the name in another variable. How do we do this is java?

I have implemented some code somewhat like this:

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
  char character = scanner.hasNextChar(); // doesn't exist but idk how 
  String name = scanner.hasNext(); 
}
}
```

Basically I have a while loop reading each 2 elements line by line and in each line there is a for loop to store each element in a variable. I am just confused on how to extract each separate element in java.

Comment: It's a common CSV/TSV handling. Split the line String by the character that's the delimiter of the column

Comment: Personally I would split this into two parts: 1 retrieving the line and 2 verifying the line and retrieving the components. The first one can be performed using Scanner if you so like, the latter is better done using regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you're using `scanner.hasNextLine()` as your loop condition. You can split the `String` then collect the result as needed.

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
     String[] result = scanner.nextLine().split(" "); 
     char character = result[0].charAt(0);
     String name = result[1];
}
```

Comment: This method works, but what would be the solution if the next line of text didn't need to be split. Like in my example what if the next line was just 'f' without the name following it. The next line is not put in the result array. How can I include that character as well?

Comment: @MorganHenry Alright, what you could do is wrap the code inside the while loop with `if(scanner.nextLine().contains(" ")){ ....} else{ // get data without space here and process it as required}`

Comment: actually trim it first i.e `if(scanner.nextLine().trim().contains(" ")){ ....} else{ // get data without space here and process it as required}`

Answer (score 0):

You can split the line with the whitespace character by using the `String.split(String regex)` method.
It will produce an array of two String.

If you invoke `while(scanner.hasNextLine()){` to get an input, you should invoke     `String name = scanner.nextLine();`  to retrieve the input.

The `hasNext()` method returns a boolean to indicate if this scanner has another token in its input. 

 Doing `while(scanner.hasNextLine()){` and `scanner.hasNext()` is redundant.