# Do I scan twice if I call scanner.hasNext and then scanner.next

Tags: java, parsing, tokenize, lexer

Do I scan twice if I call `scanner.hasNext(pattern)` and then `scanner.next(pattern)` with the same pattern on `java.util.Scanner`

Let's say i have this code with a lots of cases (trying to make a lexer):

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MainClass {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner("Hello World! 3 + 3.0 = 6 ");

      Pattern a = Pattern.compile("..rld!");
      Pattern b = Pattern.compile("...llo");


      while(scanner.hasNext()) {
         if (scanner.hasNext(a)) {
            scanner.next(a);
            /*Do something meaningful with it like create a token*/
         }
         else if(scanner.hasNext(b)) {
            scanner.next(b);
         }
         /*...*/
      }


      // close the scanner
      scanner.close();
   }
}
```

My questions are:

- Does the `hasNext(pattern)` caches somehow the result of the search? So it doesn't search the same pattern twice
- Is this slower or faster than using `try { scanner.next(pattern) } catch { ... }`
- Or is there an easier way (without third-party libraries) to tokenize based on the regex patterns

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Scanner hasNext() and hasNextLine() to retrieve 2 elements per line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619023/using-scanner-hasnext-and-hasnextline-to-retrieve-2-elements-per-line)

Comment: Sadly not. The problem isn't separating by a whitespace but getting a token from the input, but without knowing which token will come next. Thus need for multiple regexes, which i need to check separately

Comment: The reason i can't skip whitespaces is that i need to parse strings as well so i wouldn't know how many of them i've skipped over

Comment: Ok so I found out that the Scanner still needs to skip over whitespaces so it is useless now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I think that the answer is:

Documentation doesn't say anything so it may be possible, but it probably does not.

---

Also, I was primarily asking because i wanted to use it for parsing more complex things like string literals and not just white space separated tokens.
And found out that Scanner still takes such token and then it checks if it matches. So it is now useless for my use case.

Comment: I would recommend a parser generator. You define a grammar and the generator generates the java parser. Here an example: https://javacc.github.io/javacc/

Comment: Thank you for great option. But unfortunately i need it for a school project and we have to use standard java and scala libraries. But I still thank you for a very useful information for other people who stumble upon this question :-)

Comment: Then I would recommend:
1. Make a list of token patterns.
2. Create a regex with capturing groups
3. Use the groups to determine the token type

If you save the capture group name and the regex in a class you can reuse them nicely: http://giocc.com/writing-a-lexer-in-java-1-7-using-regex-named-capturing-groups.html

Comment: That's exactly what i did but not with scanner. I made custom class with BufferedReader inside that matches Patterns. The reason i couldn't do it with Scanner is that scanner takes the delimiter and splits the input into separate tokens before it performs any matching. Initially i did not expect that but if i tried to match a pattern with `[0-9]+` on input that contained `0x32` it didn't recognized it. Which makes me believe that it wouldn't recognize pattern `"[^"]+"` with input that looks like `"hello    <space>    world"`